# IntelliJ IDEA - change color of a separated code editors margin

Tags: intellij-idea, colors, configuration, themes

I want to change color of a margin of separated code editors.

To be precise:

- you have two files open in editor
- on one file you click with your right mouse button
- click "Split Down"
- now you have two code editors (two files, two panels) in one window

I want to change color of a margin between this two files (as the red line shows):
Now it's black and it's hard to see where one code ends and second begins.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible. Please, vote for [IDEA-146953](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146953) and follow for updates.